# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una función que tras hacer varios cálculos acaba con 3 variables de tipo float. Al retornarlas me da el siguiente error, ¿que significa?

> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

```
def funcion():
    ...
    a = float1
    b = float2
    c = float3
    return a,b,c

a, b, c = funcion(param_anterior)
```

No entiendo porque es un error de tipo si yo acabo con tres valores, que son los que retorno y son con los que voy a querer trabajar en un futuro.

Comment: A la función le estás pasando un parámetro que no recibe

Comment: Vale, pero porque no recibe los parámetros si yo los tengo allí? @JimyHendrixFalcónCárdenas

Comment: Probablemente tu funcion no alcanza la linea del return porque está dentro de un condicional o algo asi. Si una función termina su ejecución sin un return explícito, python hará que retorne `None`, lo que producirá el error que muestras. Para un diagnóstico más preciso habría que ver tu código real.